# Problem extracting tar file

Tags: command-line, tar

I have tried the command :

```
tar -xjvf FileZilla_3.7.1.1_*-linux-gnu.tar.bz2
```

After Giving this command getting these errors :

```
tar (child): FileZilla_3.7.1.1_*-linux-gnu.tar.bz2: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

What should i do?

Comment: I don't even know if `tar` supports multiple filenames in the arguments but using wildcards to extract a single archive makes no sense, just type in the exact name of the file you want to extract

Comment: @Faysal  I suggest you be careful of these kind of error next time.

Comment: @FaysalHasan remember to check the **tick** to mean that you accept my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Better check your path. Make sure that **there is** a file called this name in your current directory. It seems like there is no other special problems.

I've tested on my computer, if I enter the command (actually there is nothing called 'filezilla' on my computer), the error it came out is just like yours.

Answer (score 1):

`tar` can not accept multiple archive files as input (although you can use wildcard to extract only selected files from the archive). Whatever the first argument to be passed after `-f` to `tar -xf` would be treated as archive and all other files would be treated as the files to be extracted. So, in you case `tar` will look for a file named `FileZilla_3.7.1.1_*-linux-gnu.tar.bz2` and if `tar` can not find that file it will complain.

A way to untar multiple files at once is to use;

```
ls *.tar.bz2 | xargs -i tar xjf {}
```

Comment: be careful with piping `ls`, better use `find name '*tar.bz2' -print0 | xarg -0`, or simply the `-exec tar xjf '{}' \;` option in find.